# Что такое Христос Пантократор в мандоре?

Tags: значение-слов

Интересует *мандор* или *мандора* - не нашла. Кроме цитруса, который пусть отдыхает, гибрид нищасный.

> Таких произведений, как капелла Зенона, до наших дней сохранилось
>   ничтожно мало (Равенна). Это настоящая роскошь – небольшое
>   пространство щедро украшено мозаикой. Над нами Христос Пантократор в
>   мандоре, и к славе возносят Его, в золотые небеса, златокудрые ангелы.
>   По сторонам ещё несколько значимых для раннего христианства композиций
>   – таких, как Престол уготованный.

Ранее было:

> И если приступим сразу к чтению главной мысли, то обнаружим, что
>   вверху первой триумфальной арки здесь изображен *Христос во Славе*.
>   Так называется канон, в котором его фигура предстает в окружении
>   ангелов и/или в своеобразном вытянутом круге – мандоре.

Кстати, в столь торжественном тексте как смотрятся рукотворные ***и/или***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**мандо́рла**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/59901/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B0)
(от итал. mandorla «миндалина») — в христианском и буддийском искусстве особая форма нимба, сияние овальной формы, вытянутое в вертикальном направлении, внутри которого помещается изображение Будды, Христа или Богоматери (реже святых).
Изображение Христа в мандорле особенно свойственно иконографии Преображения Господня и Второго Пришествия; **мандорла передает здесь сияние славы Господней.**

Мандорла может иметь как вытянутую, овальную форму, так и форму круга.
Цвет мандорлы, поскольку символизирует сияние, состоит из колец, расположенных в порядке высветления — либо к центру, либо к краям. Сама мандорла часто бывает изображена пронизанной тонкими золотыми лучами, либо эти лучи также могут быть написаны белой краской. Цвет мандорлы обычно сине-голубой или красный, иногда она позолачивается.
На иконе преподобного Андрея Рублёва «Преображение Господне» из праздничного чина иконостаса мандорла изображена иссиня чёрным цветом.

Синонимы: символ, сияние.

Живописцы эпохи Возрождения порой окружали мандорлой фигуры не только Спасителя и Приснодевы, но и святых, которых хотели изобразить во славе.

Ещё о мандорле и ее разновидностях можно посмотреть [**здесь**](http://pravoslavie.ru/282.html) и [**здесь**](http://kustodiev-art.ru/?item=e7f68878-8915-4d5e-b762-5411c44204e0&termin=ab08d096-248c-4e35-8c2b-2174c332834f).

**Так называется канон, в котором его фигура предстает в окружении ангелов и в своеобразном вытянутом круге – мандорле.**

Comment: Римулечка, спасибо-преспасибо!!! )))